# Swap function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, swap

I'm starting my adventure with Haskell language and I need a little help. How should I define swap function which is declared:

```
swap :: (Int, Char) -> (Char, Int)
```

Probably it's very easy, but I have problem with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```haskell
swap :: (Int, Char) -> (Char, Int)
swap (a, b) = (b, a)
```

You might want to read up on [pattern matching](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) in Haskell.

Comment: So easy. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 9):

You can also be more general with:

```hs
swap :: (a, b) -> (b, a)
swap (x, y) = (y, x)
```

This works for all types, not just for `Int` and `Char`.